# Servo, control, rpm sensor in high g environment

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, embedded-systems

I've used a few types of mechanically actuated variable pitch props on my boat, so I know their performance is good.  However, their strictly mechanical and also self-contained nature makes their operation unreliable.  I'm looking into the feasibility of an electrically actuated one for my own use, and I have a few questions.  Since a prop must bolt on to an existing shaft drive, it has to be fully self-contained- no levers or wires connected externally.  Lots of challenges here, but the biggest that I'm having trouble finding info on is the g-force question.  At 4k rpms, say 2" off center, that's suddenly 900 gs of acceleration.  Will any servo or controller be able to handle that?

I'd like to measure the RPM internally as well, though potentially I could mount a magnet on the drive to count passes/rpms that way.  But an accelerometer on board would be neater.  Again, could it handle the gs?

I'll certainly entertain discussion of moving everything to the center (not ideal), but even then any part of a component that extends to 1" from center would see 500 gs.

Comment: This really sounds more like a mechanical design question than an electrical one. The general answer is yes, electronics can be mounted in ways that handle high acceleration. But you need to figure out a lot more first, such as the forces that a servo would have to generate, where the power for that servo would come from, whether you have room for all of this inside the hub, etc.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I appreciate your input.  I'd really rather concentrate on my question, rather than the separate questions of servo force, power, and layout.  I'm working on those elsewhere.  If you really think my question about g forces vs electronics belongs in a mechanical engineering forum, I'll defer to your judgement.  If not, maybe we could put this back in electrical?

Comment: Having an accelerometer on the shaft seems like a very odd idea to me. I doubt you'd find one which could handle those g's let alone measure them, unless you had a g-reduction mechanism. IMO An optical system would be the easiest and most reliable